# R fpp3 package on Databricks

Tags: r, databricks

I am trying to install R fpp3 package on Databricks

```
install.packages('fpp3', dependencies = TRUE)
```

I am getting tons of errors like:

```
ERROR: dependencies ‘vctrs’, ‘rlang’, ‘generics’, ‘numDeriv’, ‘ggplot2’, ‘scales’, ‘farver’, ‘digest’, ‘lifecycle’ are not available for package ‘distributional’
```

I am fixing it by installing it one by one. Is there way to accomplish it quicker?

Answer (score 1):

Make a vector, `v` of the dependencies like `c("pkg1","pkg2") and then

`install.packages(v)`

Comment: Thank you, I did it, but the issue is that I keep adding more and more packages to this list. This is endless. Nothing like this happens on my local PC.